# Best approach to build factless fact in star schema DWH

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have a case where I'm building factless fact table for my DWH. There are 2 dimension that I want to ask for this case: location and store. I have 2 approach.

1. Building dim_store and fact_account. Then put all the location data into the fact_account table
2. Building dim_store, dim_location, and fact_account. Then put the store_id and location_id on the fact_account

Here is the visualization for these 2 approaches:

1.
[image: FIRST APPROACH]

2.
[image: SECOND APPROACH]

Which is the best approach and why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi - a dimensional model should be designed round your reporting requirements, so without knowing what those are it is difficult to comment in a design. Can a location only be associated to a store (and not a residence/office/factory/etc)? If so then why not denormalise the location data into the store dimension? BTW option 1 is definitely wrong as a fact table should never contain attributes unless they are degenerate dimensions?

Comment: The first approach is called **denormalization**. And BTW you have a third option where you *denormalize* both dimensions and ends only with the fact table. A *denormalization* is neither good nor bad. It depends on you query and processing pattern. You need more storage but you can speed up some queries. And - do not forget - *you* are responsible for keeping consistency in the denormalized schema.

Comment: @NickW I'm going to have other dimensions such as suppliers, warehouse, etc etc and consolidate all on fact_account.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Yup I know the denormalization process and thank you for pointing that out.  So if I have other fact tables - for example fact_sales and fact_order that contains store and their order, I'm not maintaining the store on the dimension, but instead on the fact tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is definitely wrong, what is described there is not a dimensional model.

Option 2 is a correctly designed dimensional model. Whether it is the best way to dimensionally model your data depends on your reporting requirements.